# Terraform Pass Cosmos Database Connection String to KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, azure-cosmosdb, azure-keyvault

I have recently created a cosmos database in Terraform and I am trying to pass its database connection string as a secret in keyvault, but when doing this I get the following error:

`Error: Incorrect attribute value type │  │   on keyvault.tf line 282, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Authentication_Server_Cosmos_DB_ConnectionString": │  282:   value        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb.connection_strings  │     ├──────────────── │     │ azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb.connection_strings has a sensitive value │  │ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.`

I have also tried to use the sensitive argument but key vault does not like that argument also I cant find any documentation on how to do this. On the Terraform website it just has it listed as an attribute you can call on.

My Terraform Secret code is bellow, I wont put all my code in here as Stack overflow doesn't like the amount of code that I have.

So please presume, I am using the latest Azurerm agent, and all the rest of my code is correct its just the secret part that's not working.

```html
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Authentication_Server_Cosmos_DB_ConnectionString" { //Auth Server Cosmos Connection String Secret
  name         = "AuthenticationServerCosmosDBConnectionString"
  value        = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb.connection_strings 
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.nscsecrets.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.service_principal,
    azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb,
  ]

}
```

Comment: any specific reason that you want to use connection string? why not primary key and endpoint

Comment: Because the .Net Dev has the app programmed to look for the connection string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **4 connection Strings** inside the value that you have given and also the values are of type `secure_string` . So you need to convert them to `String` Value and *apply index* for which value you want to store in the keyvault.

**For Storing all the the 4 Connection Strings you can use below :**

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  count = length(azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb.connection_strings)
  name         = "AuthenticationServerCosmosDBConnectionString-${count.index}"
  value        = tostring("${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb.connection_strings[count.index]}")
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**If you want to store only one connection string then you can use index as per your requirement *(for example : if you want to store the first `connection_string` then use '0' as index and like wise 1/2/3 .)* in the below code:**

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example1" {
  name         = "AuthenticationServerCosmosDBConnectionString"
  value        = tostring("${azurerm_cosmosdb_account.nsauthsrvcosmosdb.connection_strings[0]}")
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: you legend knew you would know how to do this.

Comment: ha ha .. Glad to be of Help @Jason :)